# Need help understanding std::forward

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, rvalue, lvalue

In the article [Perfect forwarding and universal references in C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c)  I have one moment that I don't get.
In paragraph **Solving perfect forwarding with std::forward** first case I understand, but second no.

```
The other case to handle is:

wrapper(42, 3.14f);
Here the arguments are rvalues, so T1 is deduced to int. We get the call func(forward<int>(e1), ...). Therefore, forward is instantiated with int and we get this version of it [3]:

int&& forward(int&& t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<int&&>(t);
}
```

Wrapper is

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void wrapper(T1&& e1, T2&& e2) {
    func(forward<T1>(e1), forward<T2>(e2));
}
```

for forward author said that this overload is used in this case

```
template<class T>
T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

So after calling  wrapper(42, 3.14f); we have

```
void wrapper(int&& && e1, float&& && e2) {
        func(forward<T1>(e1), forward<T2>(e2));
```

which is deduced to

```
void wrapper(int e1, float e2) {
        func(forward<int>(e1), forward<float>(e2));
```

then calling one of forward. as it's forward(typename std::remove_reference::type& t) we still have

```
int&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<int>::type& t) noexcept 
-->

int&& forward(typename int& t) noexcept
```

So it's again

```
return static_cast<int& &&>(t);
```

which will return int&. But we should get int&& in this example. So I obviously not understanding something. For me it seems that typename std::remove_reference::type& t will always return reference, so forward's return will always be `return static_cast<T& &&>(t);`
Need help, please.

Comment: What are these `&& &&` and `& &&`? And why do you think that for `T`=`int` you get `int& &&` and not `int &&`? You can check with cppinsights (https://cppinsights.io/s/733aee77), that gives a good understanding of how the compiler interprets the code.

Comment: The search term for further research is [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing): "This, along with special rules for template argument deduction when `T&&` is used in a function template, forms the rules that make `std::forward` possible."